# Powershell 'x or y' assignment

Tags: powershell, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator, powershell-core

There are several languages that provide either a defaulting or logical or mechanism for assignment:

```
a = b || c;
a = b or c
a="${b:-$c}"
a = b ? b : c;
```

So far the only equivalent I've found in Powershell Core is the exceedingly verbose:

```
$a = if ($b) { $b } else { $c }
```

which in some cases has to become

```
$a = if ($b -ne $null) { $b } else { $c }
```

Is there a better alternative [edit:] which doesn't sacrifice readability?

Comment: [Here's a good article with an example function](http://fearthecowboy.com/powershell/2015/12/11/PowerShell-A-Better-Ternary).  It turns `=` into a function to support ternary and null coalesce.

Comment: There is a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3240) to add this to the PowerShell language; please make your voice heard there.

Comment: @mklement0 Could that be expanded to introduce ternaries or does that break the use of `Where-Object` and parsing?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Yes: there's a [related feature request to add ternary conditionals](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3239) (`Where-Object` is parsed in _argument_ mode, so there's no conflict with _expression_ mode).

Comment: @kfsone: Great question; as an aside: in order to reliably test for `$null`, `$null` must be used as the _LHS_  - `$null -ne $b` - because the RHS operand acts as a _filter_  with an _array-valued_ LHS in PowerShell (try `'foo', 'bar' -ne $null`).

Comment: @mklement0 Oh, TIL! More reason for there to be a specific operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no `||` short-circuit operator in PowerShell assignments, and nothing equivalent to Perl's `//` "defined-or" operator - but you can construct a simple [null coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) imitation like so:

```
function ?? {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,Position=0)]
    [psobject[]]$InputObject,

    [switch]$Truthy
  )

  foreach($object in $InputObject){
    if($Truthy -and $object){
      return $object
    }
    elseif($object -ne $null){
      return $object
    }
  }
}
```

Then use like:

```
$a = ?? $b $c
```

or, if you want to just have return anything that would have evaluated to `$true` like in your first example:

```
$a = ?? $b $c -Truthy
```

Comment: It's a valiant effort, but, at the end of the day, unless it is _built into the language_, it likely won't go anywhere - vote for the latter at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3240 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3239

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Great answer, but presumably you're saying "there's no such feature built-in"? If so, may I'll edit the answer with that clarification and accept it.

Comment: @kfsone fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

So a simple method for reducing this:

```
$a = if ($b -ne $null) { $b } else { $c }
```

Would be to use the fact that true and false are just one or zero and could be used as an array index like so:

```
$a =  @($c, $b)[$b -ne $null]
```

Comment: That's super neat, although I think I'd flag it as unreadable in a PR.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd have to agree with @TheIncorrigible1 -- that's a sure-fire way to turn colleagues off of learning Powershell :(